# How to customize reference format for bibtex

Tags: bibtex, xetex, formatting, cross-referencing, customize

I use bibtex to output references, but I want to customize the format of the references. My example code is as follows

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document} 

some content...

\cite{K}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{mybib}

\end{document}
```

My mybib.bib is as follows

```
@article{S,
author = {tom and jerry and others},
title = {Quasi-coherent sheaf},
journal = {abcd},
volume = {20},
number = {4},
year = {2030}
}

@article{K,
author = {mike and jerry and others},
title = {Cohomology of sheaf},
journal = {abc},
volume = {11},
number = {5},
pages = {220-230},
year = {2030}
}
```

I hope to make the following modifications:

1. The horizontal distance between the square brackets [] and the first letter of each reference name;
2. Modify the vertical distance between two references;
3. List all the authors in the article, and connect the last one with the second to last one using "and" instead of using "et al";
4. The horizontal spacing between the last author and the article title, as well as between the article title and the journal name.

How can the above modifications be implemented? Or can we output a more general custom format？

There is another small question: I have implemented a custom reference title format through `\refname`, but I hope its font is not bold. How can I achieve this?

Please give me some hints, or what information should I check? Thank you!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Are you forced to use BibTeX or would it also be an option to use `biblatex` +  `biber`? Several things are easier to configure using `biblatex`. For example 3 and 4 would IMHO need modifications of `plain.bst` when using BibTeX. And please don't mix question about the style of the bibliography heading not with questions about the style of bibliography entries. Your “small question” is a completely different one.

Comment: @cabohah Thank you very much for your reminder. I will try to make some modifications.